# Can anybody help me to get promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I need create a function 'timer' which returns a promise and takes one argument     (number of milliseconds). Promise should go into state 'fulfilled' in argument   time. It does not perform with delay of new Promise.

```
function timer(del) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) { 
        resolve(del);
    });
    setTimeout(timer, del);
};

timer(3000).then(function(val) {
    console.log ('I\'m shown in ' + (val / 1000) + ' seconds'); 
});
```

Comment: Your `timer` function returns the `Promise` before you call `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not waiting before resolving the promise, you're doing it right away in the promise executor function. The `setTimeout` is also dead code, because of the `return` before it; if the return weren't there, you'd be setting up `timer` to call itself (after a delay) every time it's run.

```
function timer(del) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(del);       // <==== You're doing this right away
    });
    // The following is dead code since you already `return`ed
    setTimeout(timer, del); // <==== This would call `timer` later, setting up a repeat
}
```

Instead, use the timer to call `resolve`:

```js
function timer(del) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, del, del);
  });
}
timer(3000).then(function(val) {
  console.log('I\'m shown in ' + (val / 1000) + ' seconds');
});
```

---

Side Note: This line

```
setTimeout(resolve, del, del);
```

works on any modern browser. For older browsers that didn't support passing arguments via `setTimeout`, you'd either do this:

```
setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, del), del);
```

or this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    resolve(del);
}, del);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function timer(del) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve();
    }, del)
  });
}
```